# Javafx user input paint color change Stroke color

Tags: java, javafx

Using javafx I am trying to set the stroke color based on the user's input (out of 3 options) but for some reason, I am only getting one color when my canvas is displayed (green) no matter what I select. I declared my variable and created a switch statement with 3 choices and tried to pass that to gc.setStroke. Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Use this template to create simple animations in FX. Change the name of the
 * class and put your own name as author below. Change the size of the canvas
 * and the window title where marked and add your drawing code in the animation
 * method where shown.
 *
 * 
 */
public class Asteroids extends Application {

    /**
     * Sets up the stage and starts the main thread. Your drawing code should
     * NOT go here.
     *
     * @param stage The first stage
     */


    public static int Asteroid, count, x, y, z, xPlayer, yPlayer, xAlien, yAlien, choice;
    public static String Score, Lives;
    public Paint playerColor, alienColor;

    @Override

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Asteroids!"); // window title here
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 450); // canvas size here
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter the score: ");
        Score = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter lives remaining: ");
        Lives = sc.nextLine();
        int LivesNum = Integer.parseInt(Lives);




        System.out.println("Enter the x co-ordinate of the player's ship (0-500): ");
        xPlayer = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the y co-ordinate of the player's ship (0-500): ");
        yPlayer = sc.nextInt();


        String menu = "Enter the color of the player spaceship using one of the number options below:\n1-RED\n2-BLUE\n3-GREEN";


        do {
            choice = 0;
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
                System.out.println(menu);
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice; must be 1, 2, or 3 only. Try again");
            }

            switch (choice) {
                    case (1):
                        playerColor = (Color.RED);
                        choice = 4;
                case (2):
                    playerColor = (Color.BLUE);
                    choice = 4;
                case (3):
                    playerColor = (Color.GREEN);
                    choice = 4;
            }
        }
        while (choice != 4) ;



        System.out.println("Enter the x co-ordinate of the alien's ship (0-500): ");
        xAlien = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the y co-ordinate of the alien's ship (0-500): ");
        yAlien = sc.nextInt();

        menu = "Enter the color of the alien spaceship using one of the number options below:\n1-RED\n2-BLUE\n3-GREEN";


        do {
            choice = 0;
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
                System.out.println(menu);
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice; must be 1, 2, or 3 only. Try again");
            }

            switch (choice) {
                case (1):
                    alienColor = (Color.RED);
                    choice = 4;
                case (2):
                    alienColor = (Color.BLUE);
                    choice = 4;
                case (3):
                    alienColor = (Color.GREEN);
                    choice = 4;
            }
        }
        while (choice != 4) ;


        System.out.println("Enter the number of asteroids: ");
        Asteroid = sc.nextInt();

        count = 0;
            while (count < Asteroid) {
                System.out.println("Enter the x co-ordinate of the center of the asteroid (0-500): ");
                x = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the y co-ordinate of the center of the asteroid (0-500): ");
                y = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the asteroid size in pixels (0-500): ");
                z = sc.nextInt();
                gc.fillRect(x, y, z,z);
                count += 1;

        }












        stage.show();
        // This code starts a "thread" which will run your animation
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> animate(gc));
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * Animation thread. This is where you put your animation code.
     *
     * Note: Although most of what you will do will probably work, there is a
     * possibility of the application appearing to freeze after a while because
     * the drawing is not happening in a thread safe way. If this is happening,
     * create a private draw() method with parameters for x, y, etc. to do the
     * actual drawing work, then call it like this...
     *
     * Platform.runLater(() -> {
     *      draw(x,y...);
     * });
     *
     * @param gc The drawing surface
     */
    public void animate(GraphicsContext gc) {


        gc.setStroke(playerColor);
        gc.strokeOval(xPlayer, yPlayer, 31, 31);
        gc.setStroke(alienColor);
        gc.strokeOval(xAlien, yAlien, 25, 25);
        gc.fillText("Score: " + Score, 20,15);
        gc.fillText("Lives: " + Lives, 40,30);
        gc.fillText("Delano Petrilli, 2021", 300,425);





    }



    /**
     * Use this method instead of Thread.sleep(). It handles the possible
     * exception by catching it, because re-throwing it is not an option in this
     * case.
     *
     * @param duration Pause time in milliseconds.
     */
    public static void pause(int duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exits the app completely when the window is closed. This is necessary to
     * kill the animation thread.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the app
     *
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a GUI application. Do not use standard input to get data from the user. Add controls, such as [javafx.scene.control.TextField](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html)

Comment: Take a look at your `switch` statement. What are you missing between cases? But I recommend you follow Abra's advice—use the GUI to get user input.